# How do I import a source file using minted

Tags: minted

Currently, I have something like this:

```
\begin{minted}{csharp}
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
}
\end{minted}
```

Where the source code is copy/pasted from a source file.

Is there any way to include the full file within the `minted` section?

That way, when my code changes, my PDF will automatically update.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`minted` has `\inputminted[<options>]{<language>}{<filename>}` that might help you. According to the documentation, this command is used to read and format whole files.

Let's say you have your code inside `hello.cs`:

```or-tag-here
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
}
```

Then, in your LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\inputminted{csharp}{hello.cs}

\end{document}
```

The output is as expected:

[image: Output]

Hope it helps. `:)`